# xargs ignoring part of command after &&

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xargs

I intend to get a comma separated list of files and then pass it as argument to a command using xargs.

However it seems xargs ignores the part of command after &&.

```
$ find */build* -printf '%h/%f,'
jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,


$ find */build* -printf '%h/%f,' | xargs -t python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge && python3 -m coverage xml --omit
python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,
Couldn't combine from non-existent path 'jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,'
```

So, the command is interpreted as:

`python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,`

Expected:

`python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge && python3 -m coverage xml --omit  jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,`

Any pointer will be a great help.

Comment: **It's not `xargs`.** The _shell_ breaks that input into two commands: one `find ... | xars ..

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah I see the point now. Thanks. Can you please suggest which commands can I explore to achieve what I am trying to get at. I am not well versed with shell utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta: I wrote a much longer comment that Stack seems to have discarded somehow, so I am re-doing as an answer to get edit history even though I'm not sure this is really programming (and thus may need to be deleted).

**It's not xargs.** The shell breaks that input into two commands, and then executes the first pipeline by running `find */build* -printf '%h/%f,'` as one process with stdout connected to a pipe and `xargs -t python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge` as another process with stdin connected to that same pipe; only after both of these complete, and only if the `xargs` is successful which in turn is only if the `python3 -m ...` is successful which it wasn't, the shell would run the second command `python3 -m coverage xml --omit` as a third process.

You could pass the `&&` to `xargs` by quoting it: any of `'&&' "&&" \&\&`. However `xargs` is not a shell and will not interpret the `&&` as an 'and' operator; it will run *one* `python3` process with arguments `-m coverage combine python-bridge && python3 -m coverage xml --omit` with the (one) input 'filename' `jenkins/build.jenkinsfile,jenkins/build-x.groovy,` appended, and that won't work either.

You *can* have `xargs` run a shell which in turn runs the commands you want:

```
find */build* -printf '%h/%f,' | 
xargs -t sh -c 'python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge && python3 -m coverage xml --omit $*' dummy0'
# in general you should use "$@" to prevent split+glob from mangling 'special' arguments
# but here they have already survived xargs default parsing so shouldn't be special
```

But much simpler is to arrange your commands more appropriately:

```
python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge && 
find */build* -printf '%h/%f,' | python3 -m coverage xml --omit
```

or since this works correctly only if the list of files fits in one command so you don't actually want `xargs` main functionality, just

```
python3 -m coverage combine python-bridge && 
python3 -m coverage xml --omit $(find */build* -printf '%h/%f,')
```